# Yii2 Swiftmailer can't send image and font awesome icons

Tags: php, yii2, html-email, yii2-advanced-app

Mu Controller Code:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $data = $this->renderPartial('receivers/contact_form_output_quick_query', [
            'model' => $model,
            'formData' => $_REQUEST], true);
    $receiver_message = $this->renderPartial('receivers/receiver_message_quick_query',['data' => $data]);

    $message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose();
    $message->setFrom('info@company.com')
    ->setTo('info@company.com')
    ->setSubject('Subject Of email')
    ->setHtmlBody($data)
    ->send();

    $message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose();
    $message->setFrom('info@company.com')
    ->setTo($model->email)
    ->setSubject('Reply: Online Query')
    ->setHtmlBody($receiver_message)
    ->send();


    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Congratulations! Your message has been successfully Sent.');
}
```

Will some one tells me what is the main reason that image and Font Awesome icons are not sending properly?

My receiver message partial view goes here:

```
<div>
    <table style="width: 600px;">

        <tr>
            <td>Thanks for your interest in our services. We have received your online query.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thanks again for contacting us.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 5px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>(It may take some time depending upon the number of queries in the pipeline. We appreciate your cooperation in this regard.)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Regards!</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <?= $this->render('signature'); ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><strong style="font-size:16px;">Query Details that we received:</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $data; ?></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

The above is the render partial view for the receiver message:

My signature partial view is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="<?= $this->theme->baseUrl?>/images/email_signature.png">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="height: 30px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>+123456778</td>
    <td colspan="2"> |  +123456778</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>http://www.example.com</td>
    <td>|  info@company.com  </td>
    <td>|  <b>Skype:</b>  skypeid</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> Linked In | </a></td>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook | </a></td>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> https://www.twitter.com</a></td>
</tr>
```

The above is the render partial view for signature containing image and font awesome icons main problem is in this file.

Comment: You don't see font avesome icon in the email client?

Comment: Yes font awesome and as well as image

Comment: In the client like gmail external css doesn't work

Comment: is there any alternate solution to add image and icons

Comment: you have to use inline css, or you can use an inliner processor to make inline your css.

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Images

`$this->theme->baseUrl` will return path to theme, but without domain and scheme part (for example it will return `/themes/my-theme`). When you're generating URLs for mailing, you need to full URL with scheme and domain - you should generate URLs like this:

```
<img src="<?= Yii::$app->request->getHostInfo() . $this->theme->getBaseUrl() ?>/images/email_signature.png">
```

### Font Awesome Icons

I have a bad news for you - many clients (especially webmails) does not support webfonts, so you will not be able to use Font Awesome icons in this way. Support for SVG is even worse, so this is not a solution either. You should probably stick to good old PNGs as icons.

Unfortunately working with mailing is like a time travel - you should build your emails in the same way you created your websites 10-20 years ago. Forget about fancy CSS3 features - the most bulletproof templates are still built using tables with inline CSS everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Not every mail client supports webfonts. So probably best for you is to download it as images, save it in your public assets folder and invoke it with `img` element tag.

Comment: Ok i add the image but image is also not sending but when i check before sending email image is there but not sent in the email. May be in partial view it is not working any idea?

Comment: Where do you send your emails? If you are sending it to hotmail, gmail then they will not probably show up because those services uses their service to download image and your localhost is not available to them.

Answer (score 0):

if I am not wrong you need to use `embed()` or `attach()` for showing inline images in the email.

```
$Imageid = $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('path/to/image') 
       ->setDisposition('inline'));
```

and then use the `$cid` for showing the image inside the email text where ever you are assigning the text for the email

```
<img src="' . $Imageid . '" alt="Image" />'
```